# Tensorflow Binary Classification Cost not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using binary classification for the Titanic dataset on Kaggle. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import os

ROOT = "data"
TEST = "test.csv"
TRAIN = "train.csv"

rate = 0.01
epochs = 100
errors = []

def load_data():
    train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(ROOT, TRAIN))
    test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(ROOT, TEST))
    return [train, test]

train, test = load_data()

y_train = train['Survived'].values.reshape((891, 1))
x_train = train.drop(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Sex'], 1)
x_train['temp'] = y_train
x_train = x_train.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
y_train = x_train['temp'].values.reshape((714, 1))
x_train = x_train.drop(['temp'], 1)

x_test = test.drop(['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Sex'], 1)
x_test = x_train.dropna(axis=0, how='any') 

theta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(x_train.columns), 1]))
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, len(x_train.columns)])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
b = tf.Variable(0.0)

model = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, theta) + b)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=model))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate).minimize(cost)

init = [tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for e in range(epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x_train, y:y_train})
        loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:x_train, y:y_train})
        print("cost at step", e, loss)
        errors.append(loss)
    theta = np.array(sess.run(theta))
    b = np.array(sess.run(b))
```

I begin to clean the data (I know I could use numerical representation, but I tried to make it easy for myself) and split it into test and train. I used a sigmoid cost function, but for some reason, the cost never changes after 100 epochs. I don't know whether the problem is my cost function, or something else.

Comment: `sigmoid` is applied in cross entropy, so remove the sigmoid from the logits (model)

Comment: Doesn't the sigmoid cross entropy mean the loss formula? In that case, we use h(x) which is defined as sigmoid(theta(transpose) * x)